# Terminated app due to Memory error

Tags: xcode, swift, uiimage

Everything was fine but when I connected my app with my device.

After I see some images by clicking on a button this error comes.

I am using many images so when person clicks on a button it shows random different image.

I don't know why its showing this error, I looked at many questions similar to this but did not find any solution.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    ButtonStyle()


    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), forBarMetrics: UIBarMetrics.Default)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.translucent = true



    let quote = randomQuote()
    QuotesLabel.text = quote
    QuotesLabel.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    QuotesLabel.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(30)
    QuotesLabel.text = QuotesLabel.text?.uppercaseString
    QuotesLabel.numberOfLines = 0

    // random background image
    var random = arc4random_uniform(20)
    switch(random){

    case 0: ChangingBackground.image = UIImage(named: "backgroundiphone.jpg")
        break
    case 1: ChangingBackground.image = UIImage(named: "backgroundiphone2.jpg")
        break
    case 2: ChangingBackground.image = UIImage(named: "backgroundiphone3.jpg")
        break
    case 3: ChangingBackground.image = UIImage(named: "backgroundiphone4.jpg")
        break
    case 4: ChangingBackground.image = UIImage(named: "backgroundiphone5.jpg")
        break
    case 5: ChangingBackground.image = UIImage(named: "backgroundiphone6.jpg")
        break
    case 6: ChangingBackground.image = UIImage(named: "backgroundiphone7.jpg")
        break
    case 7: ChangingBackground.image = UIImage(named: "backgroundiphone8.jpg")
        break
    case 8: ChangingBackground.image = UIImage(named: "backgroundiphone9.jpg")
        break
    case 9: ChangingBackground.image = UIImage(named: "backgroundiphone10.jpg")
        break
    case 10: ChangingBackground.image = UIImage(named: "backgroundiphone11.jpg")
        break
    case 11: ChangingBackground.image = UIImage(named: "backgroundiphone12.jpg")
        break
    case 12: ChangingBackground.image = UIImage(named: "backgroundiphone13.jpg")
        break
    case 13: ChangingBackground.image = UIImage(named: "backgroundiphone14.jpg")
        break
    case 14: ChangingBackground.image = UIImage(named: "backgroundiphone15.jpg")
        break
    case 15: ChangingBackground.image = UIImage(named: "backgroundiphone16.jpg")
        break
    case 16: ChangingBackground.image = UIImage(named: "backgroundiphone17.jpg")
        break
    case 17: ChangingBackground.image = UIImage(named: "backgroundiphone18.jpg")
        break
    case 18: ChangingBackground.image = UIImage(named: "backgroundiphone19.jpg")
        break
    case 19: ChangingBackground.image = UIImage(named: "backgroundiphone20.jpg")
        break

    default:
        break;

    }

}


@IBAction func MotivateButtonTapped(sender: UIButton) {

    let quote = randomQuote()
    QuotesLabel.text = quote
    QuotesLabel.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    QuotesLabel.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(30)
    QuotesLabel.text = QuotesLabel.text?.uppercaseString
    QuotesLabel.numberOfLines = 0

    // random background image
    var random = arc4random_uniform(20)
    switch(random){

    case 0: ChangingBackground.image = UIImage(named: "backgroundiphone.jpg")
        break
    case 1: ChangingBackground.image = UIImage(named: "backgroundiphone2.jpg")
        break
    case 2: ChangingBackground.image = UIImage(named: "backgroundiphone3.jpg")
        break
    case 3: ChangingBackground.image = UIImage(named: "backgroundiphone4.jpg")
        break
    case 4: ChangingBackground.image = UIImage(named: "backgroundiphone5.jpg")
        break
    case 5: ChangingBackground.image = UIImage(named: "backgroundiphone6.jpg")
        break
    case 6: ChangingBackground.image = UIImage(named: "backgroundiphone7.jpg")
        break
    case 7: ChangingBackground.image = UIImage(named: "backgroundiphone8.jpg")
        break
    case 8: ChangingBackground.image = UIImage(named: "backgroundiphone9.jpg")
        break
    case 9: ChangingBackground.image = UIImage(named: "backgroundiphone10.jpg")
        break
    case 10: ChangingBackground.image = UIImage(named: "backgroundiphone11.jpg")
        break
    case 11: ChangingBackground.image = UIImage(named: "backgroundiphone12.jpg")
        break
    case 12: ChangingBackground.image = UIImage(named: "backgroundiphone13.jpg")
        break
    case 13: ChangingBackground.image = UIImage(named: "backgroundiphone14.jpg")
        break
    case 14: ChangingBackground.image = UIImage(named: "backgroundiphone15.jpg")
        break
    case 15: ChangingBackground.image = UIImage(named: "backgroundiphone16.jpg")
        break
    case 16: ChangingBackground.image = UIImage(named: "backgroundiphone17.jpg")
        break
    case 17: ChangingBackground.image = UIImage(named: "backgroundiphone18.jpg")
        break
    case 18: ChangingBackground.image = UIImage(named: "backgroundiphone19.jpg")
        break
    case 19: ChangingBackground.image = UIImage(named: "backgroundiphone20.jpg")
        break

    default:
        break;

    }




}
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


// here is the image
```

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2z_d4wEKPEFMU5lSjBqYTJtX1k/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Show `ChangingBackground`, the problem is not in the code in the Question. Use Instruments to determine where the code is being retained. BTW, conventions are that only class named begin withy an uppercase letter, method and variable names begin with a lowercase letter. From those conventions `ChangingBackground` is a class. The same applies to`QuotesLabel`. Observing conventions allows others to more easily understand other's code.

Comment: @zaph i dont know how to find this i have never done something like this i really want this to debug

Comment: Add the code for `ChangingBackground`. Add breakpoints and println() statements. Aside: One night in the computer room I asked RIck for some help, he gave me the best advice that has served me a lifetime even though I did not appreciate it at the time and you won't either: "Read the manual." I did read the manual and put in the extra effort to understand what it said; and I solved my problem and many more in the years to come. Sometimes it takes days and I mean 12+ hour days to solve a problem. Examine every statement until you know exactly why it is there and what it does.

Comment: @zaph man i tried to find the leak through instrument but didnot found.Iedited the code and pasted the link at last.You can see the image.

Comment: @zaph i guess i found the problem.the problem is the dimensions because my every image have 4425 * 2950 or more than that.can we decrease the dimensions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the images are 4425 * 2950 and given 4 bytes perplex each one will require 52+ MB when rendered. There are a couple of options:

1. If the images are part of the app reduce the size prior adding to the app, use any of a number of graphics programs to do this, I use [Graphic Converter](http://www.lemkesoft.de/en/products/graphicconverter/).
2. If pre-reduction in size is not possible as soon as loading scale the image, put this code inside an autorelease pool `autoreleasepool { scalling code }` so the temporary memory will be released as soon as possible.
3. If you need the images at this size for example panning, and since the size is substantially larger than the display area create tiles prior to adding to the project and use a tiling algorithm, an example of this is Apple Maps.